# RetryListener not bound to consumer's RetryTemplate in Spring Cloud Stream functional model

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder

We have developed a `RetryListener` to log exceptions between every retry when we are consuming messages off of a stream and exceptions occur. I am trying to bind this listener into our consumer but am not seeing the expected logged error. It appears to me that any user-defined `RetryListener`s are not being picked up by the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-binder` in our integration tests as I am not seeing the expected output logged. What do I need to do to get my `RetryListener` bound to the `RetryTemplate` created by the subclass of `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder`? Also, if my `RetryListener` is not bound via the test binder, will it be with the Kinesis and Kafka binders?

For more context, here's what we used to have when we used `@StreamListener`s:

```
@Retryable(
      maxAttemptsExpression =
          "#{@properties.maxAttemptsExpression()}",
      backoff =
          @Backoff(
              delayExpression =
                  "#{@properties.delayExpression()}",
              multiplierExpression =
                  "#{@properties.multiplierExpression()}",
              maxDelayExpression =
                  "#{@properties.maxDelayExpression()}"),
      listeners = {"myListenerSupport"})
```

Now we have the following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-message-processing-microservice
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: xyzConsumer
    stream:
      bindings:
        xyzConsumer-in-0:
          consumer:
            back-off-initial-interval: 1000
            back-off-max-interval: 10000
            back-off-multiplier: 2.0
            max-attempts: 3
```

Again, the question overall is how to I integrate my `RetryListener` into each consumer?

Comment: This looks like possibly a bug. Would you please raise an issue in Github?